# How to deploy a Qt application on Mac OS X using macdeployqt?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, deployment

I am having problems packaging my Qt app for Mac OS X using macdeployqt.

On my Mac, I have Qt5 installed on ~/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64 (this is where the bin/ and lib/ folder resides)

I have a Qt application called "renamer" on ~/Documents/QtProjects/renamer/.

Using Qt Creator, I have built the release version of my application on ~/Documents/QtProjects/build-renamer-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Release.
So the first thing I did was run `otool` on my application:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/QtProjects/build-renamer-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Release
$ otool -L renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer
renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer:
    /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

I have manually corrected the broken paths using `install_name_tool`:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/QtProjects/build-renamer-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Release
$ install_name_tool -change /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer
$ install_name_tool -change /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer
$ install_name_tool -change /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore  /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer
$ otool -L renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer
renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer:
    /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /Users/paul/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/clang_64/lib/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

I have added /bin to my PATH and then called `macdeployqt` from my project directory.

```
$ cd ~/Documents/QtProjects/build-renamer-Desktop_Qt_5_1_0_clang_64bit-Release
$ sudo macdeployqt renamer.app
$ otool -L renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer
renamer.app/Contents/MacOS/renamer:
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/5/QtWidgets (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtGui.framework/Versions/5/QtGui (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    @executable_path/../Frameworks/QtCore.framework/Versions/5/QtCore (compatibility version 5.1.0, current version 5.1.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /System/Library/Frameworks/AGL.framework/Versions/A/AGL (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 56.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

However, when I rename/remove the installed Qt libraries and run the application, I get an error indicating that the Qt libraries cannot be found within my app bundle. Any suggestions?

Comment: "When I rename/remove the installed Qt libraries..." - Are you referring to the point at which you correct the double forward slash with install_name_tool, or is this something else? Note that Qt 5.1.1 fixes the incorrect path issue with macdeployqt

Comment: Yes, you are right! I installed Qt 5.1.1 this morning and was able to use `macdeployqt` to successfully deploy my app. Now when I rename/remove Qt, my app still runs without any problems.